Why did Android Studio Jellyfish stop showing my CPP files?
Starting with Android Studio Jellyfish I can no longer see my CPP files in the Project window. I’ve always seen them until upgrading.

This is what’s in my app’s build.gradle file.
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path "src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
        version "3.22.1"
    }
}

Is this a known bug or is there something new I need to do starting with Jellyfish?

If you can reproduce the problem in a fresh project, consider opening a bug report, including that project as evidence. I do not see a bug report for this, other than this one for an older Studio build, and where the issue did not contain its own [mcve] to help Google see the problem.

Try right-clicking on the cpp folder and hitting "Reload from Disk".

"Reload from Disk" doesn't appear in the pop-up menu when I right-click.
